# What is GIT bash on windows?

Tags: database

I am working with GIT bash recently but I don't know the purpose of it!!
I mean I can use CMD instead right? 
why it is so especial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Command Prompt, but it is easier to use GIT Bash when you have many projects among many folders, it would be annoying to do `cd PATH` over and over again, with Git BASH right-clicking will allow you to open a terminal in the directory's path, cool! Also, it is made for "git" command to work out-of-the-box for Windows (easy install)

Comment: Yes, I feel it is easire to use and colorful. 
I have just tried what u said and it is right I can right click and open any path fastly!!

Comment: I hope you found my answer helpful, please mark it as correct :)